# Expose rankings to 3rd party site

Tags: feature-request

This may be a silly question... but does stack overflow/exchange expose an api for me to access my rankings so that I can display them on a 3rd party site.

i.e. display my ranking similar to how it is shown on my stack exchange CV on my personal website?

Comment: There's [flair](http://stackoverflow.com/users/991836/user991836/flair), but I don't think that includes what you want. You mean the tag percentiles at the top of a CV?

Answer (score 1):

There's an API that can use http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage. I'm not sure what you mean by rank (reputation or user leagues) but you can get both.

You can also take a look at https://stackapps.com/ it contains applications and libraries that use the api.